# I am not able to connect my TablePlus to digital ocean postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean, remote-access, table-plus

I am getting the error Could not connect to server connection timed out. I followed [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jY5FhyiEdig).

Kindly help me.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to add your public ip address to trusted sources in settings

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ensure that:

- Your public IP address (or the IP address of the accessing server) was added to the trusted sources in your settings.
- You're using the CA certificate for the database in your connection request.